# reenter US after using medicaid for childbirth

Tags: usa

I had my baby in US, then visa was renewed and granted at embassy. Will the immigration at port of entry ask for medical bill because the bills were not asked at the embassy during renewal.

Comment: Did you use "Medicaid"? Or did you just use private hospital assistance? Was it just the baby that got it? Or you? If it was Medicaid, was it "emergency Medicaid"?

Comment: The point is, the birth was on emergency, hence the use for medicaid. Nownthe visa has been renewed at home home embassy but the question is, will the immigration ask at the point of entry even after the visa renewal at home embassy. Especially when if one comes in with the baby. Also, there was extension of stay and approbved during the birth period

Answer (score 2):

**No**, they will not ask. Immigration's job is to figure out if you are allowed to enter and try to determine if you will overstay, not make you pay your debts.

Comment: But Medicaid is not debts; it's a government means-tested insurance program. Yes, immigration's job is to figure out if you are allowed to enter, and someone who is likely to become a "public charge" is inadmissible.

Comment: The point is, the birth was on emergency, hence the use for medicaid. Nownthe visa has been renewed at home home embassy but the question is, will the immigration ask at the point of entry even after the visa renewal at home embassy. Especially when if one comes in with the baby. Also, there was extension of stay and approbved during the birth period.